# Can you separate the inputs of scanf into two types that do two separate things?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm currently writing an easy piece of code to multiply two numbers but I would like to add in an option to leave the program right at the initial prompt "press x to leave". This is what I have so far:

```
  printf(" Please input two numbers between 0 and 4000 or press x to leave: \n\n");
  scanf(" %d %d", &var1, &var2);

  if ((var1 > 4000) || (var2 > 4000) || (var1 < 0) || (var2 < 0)) {
    while (1) {
      printf(
          "\n Input out of range, please use only values between 0 and 4000 \n\n");
      return main();
    }

    while (0) {
      return (0);
    }

  }

  printf("\n Your inputs are %d and %d. \n\n", var1, var2);
  printf(" %d multiplied by %d is equal to %d \n", var1, var2, var1*var2);
```

I am still extremely new to C and I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to clarify in the `scanf()` if its input is two decimal values then go ahead, but if its a singular `char` input of `x` then immediately leave.

Is that possible?

If not then could you provide a hint as to a new direction I could look into? like another `if()` statement to verify what went into the `scanf()`?

I'm also assuming the user will ONLY input two numbers or the letter x. I've only written in the one simple if statement to clarify so far. Thank you for any information you can provide.

Comment: What `return main();` supposed to do here ? Please read this [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return) to know how it works.

Comment: i thought it returned to the main function? as in after it ran the loop it would start over at main. guess that isn't how that works! thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The `return main();` calls `main()` recursively and returns whatever value it was given to return — which probably not what was intended.  It is legitimate in C if the `main()` function was defined as `int main(void)` or equivalent; it is probably not legitimate otherwise — and it is still _not_ a good idea to call `main()` recursively.  C++ does not allow you (the programmer) to call `main()` recursively.

Comment: You need to check the return value from `scanf()` to know whether 0, 1, 2 integers were read (or EOF detected).  Without that information, you can't spot the "X marks the spot" to exit the program.

Answer (score 3):

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expects an integer value to be read.  If something that is not an integer is encountered, it stops reading and leaves the mismatched characters in the buffer.

Also, `main` should not be called recursively.

The best way to handle this is to first read in a line of text with `fgets`, then check if it's "x".  If so, break out of the reading loop.  If not, use `sscanf` to read two integers and check to make sure the return value is 2 which means 2 values were read.

```
int valid;
do {
    char line[100];

    printf(" Please input two numbers between 0 and 4000 or press x to leave: \n\n");
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

    if (strcmp(line, "x\n") == 0) {
        break;
    }

    valid = 0;
    int cnt = sscanf(line, " %d %d", &var1, &var2);
    if (cnt != 2) {
         printf("Please enter two integers");
    } else if ( (var1 > 4000) || (var2 > 4000) || (var1 < 0) || (var2 < 0)) {
        printf( "\n Input out of range, please use only values between 0 and 4000 \n\n");
    } else {
        valid = 1;
    }
} while (!valid);

printf( "\n Your inputs are %d and %d. \n\n", var1, var2);
printf(" %d multiplied by %d is equal to %d \n", var1, var2, var1*var2);
```

Comment: Congrats on (nearly) 100k.

Comment: this seems a bit too complex for me to use but i sort of understand what you are going for. there isn't an easier way of doing this? not to nitpick your code because it does work i just thought there would be a simpler answer since i'm writing this for an intro to C course and we haven't covered the fgets or strcmp really. Thanks for the tips though i'll try to use this in a simpler setting.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use scanf this way. The closest you can do is like the code given below. Hope this helps!

```
int var1, var2;
char ch;
while (1)
{
    printf("Please input two numbers between 0 and 4000\n\n");
    scanf(" %d %d", &var1, &var2);

    if ((var1 > 4000) || (var2 > 4000) || (var1 < 0) || (var2 < 0))
        printf("\n Input out of range, please use only values between 0 and 4000 \n\n");
    else
    {
        printf("\n Your inputs are %d and %d.\n", var1, var2);
        printf(" %d multiplied by %d is equal to %d \n", var1, var2, var1*var2);
        printf("Press x to leave or any other key to continue...\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        if (ch == 'x') break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but with quite a few limitations. The code provided by @dbush is actually the more elegant option here and the one provided by Gautam is simpler but doesn't do it the way you need it to be done.

It is possible though in a simpler way to achieve what you need with the following code:

Before going into the code, a slight explanation:

- Accept the 2 numbers separated by a space.
- Search the string if user has entered an `x`. This can be done using the `strcspn` method. If yes, exit, else carry on.
- Now convert the 2 numbers which are part of the string into `int`s. For this use the `atoi` method. Using it on the original string can get you the 1st number as an `int` (i.e., until the 1st `space` is encountered). By extracting the second part of the string, i.e., after the space, convert that into `int` to get the second number.

  ```
  #include<stdio.h> 
  #include<string.h> 
  #include<stdlib.h>

  int main() {
      int var1, var2, index, length, isInvalid = 0;
      char s[10], s2[10];

  //do {
    isInvalid = 0;
    printf(" Please input two numbers between 0 and 4000 or press x to leave: \n\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", s); //accept the 2 numbers or the 'x' as a string
    length = strlen(s); //calculate the length of the string

    index = strcspn(s, "x"); //check if user has entered 'x'

    //if 'x' is present its position will be stored in 'index', if not present value of index will be length of string.

    if (index < length) { //if 'x' is present
      isInvalid = 0;
      printf("\nAborted");
      return 0;
    } else { //if 'x' isn't entered
      var1 = atoi(s); //converts the first part of string(before space) to its int equivalent
      index = strcspn(s, " "); //get the postion of space
      strncpy(s2, s + index, length); //get the part of string after space
      var2 = atoi(s2); //convert the second part of string into int

      //rest is your usual code.. without your return main() part which isn't really right
      if ((var1 > 4000) || (var2 > 4000) || (var1 < 0) || (var2 < 0)) {
        printf("\n Input out of range, please use only values between 0 and 4000 \n\n");
        isInvalid = 1;
      }

      printf("\n Your inputs are %d and %d. \n\n", var1, var2);
      printf(" %d multiplied by %d is equal to %d \n", var1, var2, var1 * var2);
    }
  //} while (isInvalid);

    return 0;
  }
  ```

But keep in mind one very important drawback here: You MUST enter the 2 numbers as space separated numbers when giving input. This doesn't work with 2 clicks of the 'enter' key.